# formatting inputstream data from database in Android

Tags: android, json, formatting, client-server, inputstream

I am getting data read from a table as all rows fetched and passed each row at a time to the android client.

Now, I need to format this data as I am reading it, that is store each of the four columns data in separate string variables at the Android side so I can display them in text view.

If I don't send the data each row a time, the entire table data is concatenated in a single string and passed on to the android client.

Any tips of making this more efficient and clues on solving this, if anyone requires more clarification please ask for it.

Comment: show the code on what you've done so far... your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this the other way around. I would format this before sending it to your devices. Use something like JSON format and something like this

```
package com.switchingbrains.json;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONHelper {

    // Load JSON from URL
    public String JSONLoad(String url) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(Main.class.toString(), "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return builder.toString();

    }

}
```

You will get a string wich you can load into a JSONObject and do ANYTHING you want with it.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your suggestion "switching brains". I have a python server that sends the data to the android client. The client is using the HttpUrlConnection not httpClient. I will search if Json works with httpUrlConnection, for the time being do you have any comments on this...And @swarna plz elaborate what is unclear I don't think so there is a need of code pasting here. Thanks..

Comment: More additions, seems like JSON is the way to go. It comes with most of the languages. Currently working out on dumping data in JSON 'array' of 'values', have found few articles on json parsing using HttpUrlConnection at the android client side; will get into this later. Will update later...

Comment: So finally finished working on this, first writing the output at the server end as json formatted string, then reading and parsing the string at the Android side.